# Reference a file name in shell script inside of a "for each" block

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sh

I have a task that I would like to add more automation into. Basically, I will have a directory that has a varying amount of files that start with the letter x. I want to run a script on each of these files, and then move the file into a "completed" folder.

I only want to loop through files that have an "x" as the starting character of the filename, and then use that filename in another spot as a part of an output filename.

Something along the lines of:

```
for each (files beginning with x)
  cat (filename) | xargs ./script.sh > result-(filename);
  mv (filename) complete/;
  mv result-(filename) complete/;
end for each
```

I've been manually expanding out a shell script each time this comes up, and sizing it to exactly how many files I have, but I am sure what I am asking is possible.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum for "please-write-a-script-for-me" requests. Please consider starting with a language tutorial, ie. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: where you have `(files beginning with x)` use `x*`.  As for the syntax of a for loop, see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in x*; do
  xargs ./script.sh <"$f" >"result-$f"
  mv "$f" result-"$f" complete
done
```

Points of note:

- `cat` is short for "concatenate". If you aren't concatenating multiple files, or displaying the output of a single file to the screen unmodified, it's probably not the right tool for the job: Much more efficient to directly connect the file to your desired tool's input than to launch an extra program that does nothing but read a single file and connect that program's stdout to your next program's stdin.

  To put it differently: `<filename` connects a read-only handle on `filename` to standard input (FD 0) for the current command. `cat filename |` starts *a separate program* that reads from `filename` and writes to its stdout, with that stdout connected to the stdin of the next component of the pipeline.
- `mv` can accept multiple source arguments; there's no need to invoke it multiple times when moving multiple files to the same destination.
- `x*` is a "glob expression" which expands to a list of filenames; see [the wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for more details.
- An unescaped newline terminates a command whenever the syntax allows it to do so; thus, there's no need for terminal `;`s.
- Quoting, in shell, is evaluated on a character-by-character basis; `"result-$f"` is equivalent to `result-"$f"`, and both achieve the goal of ensuring that the expansion of the variable named `f` occurs in a context where neither string-splitting or glob expansion is performed on the result.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I appreciate it :)

Comment: BTW, consider the `-d $'\n'` argument to xargs if you're using the GNU version (and a shell such as bash supporting that extended syntax). Otherwise, lines with spaces in them will result in multiple invocations, quotes won't be treated literally, etc.

Comment: The result file could be generated straight into the `complete` directory so you don't have to move it separately.

Comment: Good to know. In this case, no lines will contain spaces or special characters, but I will remember that for future use.

Comment: @tripleee, but that would have things in `complete` when they're not really complete yet (command is still running).

Comment: @tripleee, I want it to be moved after, because this is going to take a while to run. I may have to stop the script and start it back up again. If i stop it, it would only be partially through the current file and r-file would not be complete. I would then delete r-file and run the script again and it will pick back up where it left off.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What if I wanted to add pv into the mix to see a progress bar for each file? I know there's some odd interaction between xargs and pv

Comment: @TylerCollins, depends. Progress bar on the input being read or the output being generated? And if it's the former, does it need to look into the individual files, or can it simply count how many files have been touched on at all?

Comment: @TylerCollins, ...in general, you should be able to put `pv` in the pipeline either before or after xargs; having xargs invoke pv is a thing I'd try to avoid without a compelling reason.

Comment: xargs ./script.sh <pv <"$f" >"result-$f"

Comment: No, not `<pv` -- that's trying to connect stdin of xargs from a file named `pv`, as opposed to the stdout from running a program called `pv`. And your next redirection overwrites FD 0 to be reading from `"$f"` instead of that file named `pv` anyhow. :)

Comment: ...rather: `pv "$f" | xargs ./script.sh >"result-$f"`, if your goal is to have a progress bar for each file showing the progress of that individual file. Alternately, `xargs ./script.sh | pv >"result-$f"`, if your goal is to track output being written on a per-input-file basis. OTOH, if you want a global progress bar, it's more interesting, and you should ask a separate question on that basis.